# PyTorch CUDA error: an illegal memory access was encountered

Tags: python, pytorch

Relatively new to using CUDA. I keep getting the following error after a seemingly random period of time:
RuntimeError: CUDA error: an illegal memory access was encountered

I have seen people suggest things such as using `cuda.set_device()` rather than `cuda.device()`, setting `torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = False`

but I can't seem to get the error to go away. Here are some pieces of my code:
`torch.cuda.set_device(torch.device('cuda:0'))`
`torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = False`

```
class LSTM(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, hidden_dim, num_layers, output_dim):
        super(LSTM, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim
        self.num_layers = num_layers

        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_dim, hidden_dim, num_layers, batch_first=True, dropout=0.2)

        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, output_dim)

    def forward(self, x):
        h0 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers, x.size(0), self.hidden_dim).requires_grad_().cuda()
        c0 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers, x.size(0), self.hidden_dim).requires_grad_().cuda()

        out, (hn, cn) = self.lstm(x, (h0.detach(), c0.detach()))

        out = self.fc(out[:, -1, :]) 
        
        return out

    def pred(self, x):
        return self(x) > 0
```

```
def train(model, loss_fn, optimizer, num_epochs, x_train, y_train, x_val, y_val, loss_stop=60):
    cur_best_loss = 999
    loss_recur_count = 0
    best_model = None
    for t in range(num_epochs):
        model.train()

        y_train_pred = model(x_train)

        train_loss = loss_fn(y_train_pred, y_train)

        tr_l = train_loss.item()
        
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        train_loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        model.eval()
        with torch.no_grad():  
            y_val_pred = model(x_val)

            val_loss = loss_fn(y_val_pred, y_val)

            va_l = val_loss.item()
            
            if va_l < cur_best_loss:
                cur_best_loss = va_l
                best_model = model
                loss_recur_count = 0
            else:
                loss_recur_count += 1

        if loss_recur_count == loss_stop:
            break
    if best_model is None:
        print("model is None.")
    return best_model
```

```
def lstm_test(cols, df, test_percent, test_bal, initial_shares_test, max_price, last_sell_day):
    wdw = 20
    x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test, x_val, y_val = load_data(df, wdw, test_percent, cols)

    x_train = torch.from_numpy(x_train).type(torch.Tensor).cuda()
    x_test = torch.from_numpy(x_test).type(torch.Tensor).cuda()
    x_val = torch.from_numpy(x_val).type(torch.Tensor).cuda()
    y_train = torch.from_numpy(y_train).type(torch.Tensor).cuda()
    y_test = torch.from_numpy(y_test).type(torch.Tensor).cuda()
    y_val = torch.from_numpy(y_val).type(torch.Tensor).cuda()

    input_dim = x_train.shape[-1]
    hidden_dim = 32
    num_layers = 2
    output_dim = 1
    y_preds_dict = {}
    for i in range(11):
        model = LSTM(input_dim=input_dim, hidden_dim=hidden_dim, output_dim=output_dim, num_layers=num_layers).cuda()

        r = (y_train.cpu().shape[0] - np.count_nonzero(y_train.cpu()))/np.count_nonzero(y_train.cpu())/2
        pos_w = torch.tensor([r]).cuda()

        loss_fn = torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss(pos_weight=pos_w).cuda()

        optimizer = torch.optim.AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=0.01)

        best_model = train(model, loss_fn, optimizer, 300, x_train, y_train, x_val, y_val)
        
        y_test_pred = get_predictions(best_model, x_test)
        y_preds_dict[i] = y_test_pred.cpu().detach().numpy().flatten()
```

and here is the error msg:

```
<ipython-input-5-c52edc2c0508> in train(model, loss_fn, optimizer, num_epochs, x_train, y_train, x_val, y_val, loss_stop)
     19         model.eval()
     20         with torch.no_grad():
---> 21             y_val_pred = model(x_val)
     22 
     23             val_loss = loss_fn(y_val_pred, y_val)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1049         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1050                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1051             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1052         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1053         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

<ipython-input-4-9da8c811c037> in forward(self, x)
     10 
     11     def forward(self, x):
---> 12         h0 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers, x.size(0), self.hidden_dim).requires_grad_().cuda()
     13         c0 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers, x.size(0), self.hidden_dim).requires_grad_().cuda()
     14 

RuntimeError: CUDA error: an illegal memory access was encountered
CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call,so the stacktrace below might be incorrect.
For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1.
```

Answer (score 11):

It was partially said by the answer of the OP, but the problem under the hood with illegal memory access is that the GPU runs out of memory.

In my case, when I run a script on Windows I get the error message:

```
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 1.64 GiB (GPU 0; 4.00 GiB total capacity; 1.10 GiB already allocated; 1.27 GiB free; 1.12 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)
```

but when run on Linux I get:

```
RuntimeError: CUDA error: an illegal memory access was encountered
CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call,so the stacktrace below might be incorrect.
For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1.
```

Perhaps the message in Windows is more understandable :)

References:
https://forums.fast.ai/t/runtimeerror-cuda-error-an-illegal-memory-access-was-encountered/93899

Answer (score 7):

Turns out using `torch.cuda.empty_cache()` at the end of the `for i in range(11):` loop solved the problem.

Comment: This indeed fixed the issue of illiegal memory access (must be done after the validation stage loops too), of course it adds an overhead in time as discussed https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/about-torch-cuda-empty-cache/34232/10 
But I could only solve the issue like this when dealing with big batch sizes. If I can expand on the behavior I'll add here.

Answer (score 3):

Had an issue where Pytorch Geometric was giving a similar error. Reducing the batch size worked for me - [source](https://ai-pool.com/d/pytorch-runtimeerror--cuda-error--an-illegal-memory-access-was-encountered).